# Windows XP repair installation keeps restarting

Tags: windows-xp, installation, repair, repair-install

I have a windows XP machine which was working absolutely fine until yesterday. Then suddenly it won't boot in normal mode.

Tried Safe Mode, Safe Mode Command prompt, Last known good configuration etc. but no luck. Well, in safe mode it once started but took 2 hours.

So based on various forum posts, I boot it from CD and started Window XP Repair. (not recovery console).

It copied all files, restarted machine and started installation. But got stuck at 39 minutes. I left it on overnight but it was still stuck. 
So, in the morning I hard booted by pressing power switch.

After reboot, it got the installation process on track and finished all steps like Installing Device Drivers, Menu Items, Language selection everything and restarted the machine. I now expected "Welcome to reinstalled XP" but it restarted the installation process again.

Now everytime, it goes into the installation process, finishes the installation successfully but comes back to installation after restart.

Any idea guys? This is getting on my nerves.

Thanks in advance.
Milind

Comment: do you remove the CD after the installation terminate?

Comment: First, I booted through CD, selected repair install and let it reboot, it finishes installation from hard-disk with CD installed. and then restart the machine. CD is still in the drive, it comes back to installation (second step). If I remove the CD, it still goes in the installation and asks for CD :-(

Comment: ok seems that the problem happens at second phase after windows copy the files restart and init the installation. The problem i think is connected to  some hardware problem, you can try a new installation removing all the peripheral devices you have installed and with one slot of ram(if you have more than 1), also check the CD isn't scratched or the hdd isn't faulty.

Comment: I am worried for data to try fresh installation. I have 3 partitions. If I do fresh installation, will it format full drive or it will overwrite only C drive?
I will check removing memory ( I have two sticks of 1 GB each). CD doesn't seem to have visible scratch.
Btw, its laptop Dell Inspiron 600m, if it give any clue.

Comment: it's up to you to format only one partition or all the drive, in the blue screen of installation you have the options, clear and format only C partition. you can use a win PE just to boot and copy the files from C to other partitions before you format C:/

Comment: I tried to remove both 1 GB sticks and inserted original 256 Mb stick. Now at the continuation of installation giving error "security accounts manager initialization failed 0xc0000189"